# Blender JSON export adding vertices - THREE.JS

Tags: three.js, blender

Within blender i have a simple model. When i import this model within THREE.js it seems to have gained faces and vertices. All images below. I am trying to get the middle circle face as a single face so that i can apply an image to it within THREE.js. Also is there an easy way to name a face within Blender so that it can be targeted within THREE?

Thanks all.

**Model within blender:**

[image]

**Model within THREE.js:**

[image]

**Blender export settings:**

[image]

**Importing method on THREE.js**

```
loader.load('models/poi.json', ( geometry ) => {
    console.log(geometry.faces.length); // 386 faces  
    let mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, materials );
    scene.add(mesh);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, it's not possible to name a face in Blender. Besides, the Blender JSON exporter is not supported anymore. Please use the [glTF Blender exporter](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-Exporter) and `THREE.GLTFLoader`. Moreover, faces in `three.js` are always represented as triangles. So what you are looking for (the middle circle as a single face) is not possible.

If you want to apply a texture to the center part of your mesh, assign a separate material in Blender to the group of respective faces. It's not necessary to create a single face for this. You just have to create a multi-material object.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up. For anyone wondering i found the best solution to be to remove the middle part of my model and create a .CircleGeometry within THREE.JS that i have control over and place it in the correct place related to my model.